# How to get bot id and user id via REST APIs for a bot connected to Microsoft Teams channel

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

We use `Microsoft bot` framework and have a requirement of sending a message to a bot connected to Microsoft Teams channel from an external application(running in a different environment, e.g on-premise) via REST API.  The following REST API helps to create conversation

- API : https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations
- Authorization: Bearer Token (token endpoint used:
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token)
- POST Request Body is here:

```
{
    "bot": {
        "name": "someBot",
        "id": "xxx-some-bot-id"
    },
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "some user",
            "id": "xxx-some-user-id"
        }
    ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "xxx-some-teanant-id"
    }
  },
}
```

The id returned by this API can be later used for sending messages via `/v3/conversations/{id}`

A couple of questions here:

1. Is there any REST API available to get the member Id(user id) and
       bot id used in the above payload? In other words, how does an external application can read these two internal Ids for use while
   making API call? Could not find an appropriate API in the Bot API
   doc page: [Bot Framework REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
2. Is there a way to get the tenant
       id via REST API as well for the above case? (*I understand it can be read from  Teams Application URL*)

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is something exact for what you are looking to achieve, but have you tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json#fetching-the-roster-or-user-profile? This fetches the list of members and their basic profiles(user ID/name/objectID)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a standard way to identify the team id from  the UI or via some other approach? Sorry for asking such basic question. I can find the team id from MS Team URL or by checking the network traffic. However not seen a proper way of getting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially no, you cannot retrieve the Id's externally from Teams (for privacy/spam prevention reasons). There are a few ways your bot will receive them:

- When installed in a personal context, your bot will receive message of type membersAdded that will contain the necessary information.
- If your bot is installed in a team the person is a part of, you can retrieve the roster of that team which will also contain the necessary information.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages

Comment: A couple of follow up questions:

Comment: 1.  We see bot framework REST api starts with "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/xxx". Look like Base URI is bound to data center /region. We understand that this can be read form incoming payload. What if a client wants to initiate a conversation and there is no incoming payload. In this case, how  does a client derives Base URI part of the API in a generic way?  Can we pass region(e.g amer) as some header parameter, leaving the API as "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/xxx" ?

Comment: 2. While testing, it was noticed that the following API: POST /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities works  even without ids in the payload for recipient  name and from name.  Please see the below payload, which works even without recipient user id and  from id. Is it OK to rely on this behavior ? or will this behavior change in future?
```{
    "recipient": {
        "name": "recipient"
    },
    "from": {
        "name": "somename"
    },
    "text": "Hello",
    "type": "message",
    "conversation": {
        "conversationType": "personal"
    }
}```

Comment: For 1, we recommend caching the service URL from any incoming requests your bots receive (caching per context). This value is almost always stable, but can unexpectedly change. Adding a single global URL is on the backlog for the future. For #2, that behavior is not expected to change - the Id is used for addressing, not the JSON payload.